# move trigger from one table to another trouble with syntax

Tags: mysql, triggers

I had to restore a table from a backed-up version of that table. Then I went to recreate the triggers. I can't get one re-created. I've looked at some examples of how this sort of trigger should look nothing here glares at me. I copied it from the code showed in phpmyadmin when i clicked "change" on the old trigger to save it. I thought that would be foolproof!

1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 5

```
CREATE TRIGGER `trig_parts_price_AfterUpdate` AFTER UPDATE ON `parts`
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
       IF (NEW.cost <> OLD.cost || NEW.price <> OLD.price || NEW.QtyInStock <> OLD.QtyInStock) THEN
          INSERT INTO `inv_hist_simple` (sku, cost, price, QtyInStock, change_date) 
          VALUES(OLD.sku_m, NEW.cost, NEW.price, NEW.QtyInStock, NOW());
    END IF;
END;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put this line above your code:

```
DELIMITER $$
```

and change the last line of your code to

```
END $$
```

Then add this line at the end:

```
DELIMITER ;
```

Otherwise the `;` tells the server, that the code for the trigger finishes after your insert statement, which is causing the syntax error.

So it basically should look like this:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER `trig_parts_price_AfterUpdate` AFTER UPDATE ON `parts`
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
       IF (NEW.cost <> OLD.cost || NEW.price <> OLD.price || NEW.QtyInStock <> OLD.QtyInStock) THEN
          INSERT INTO `inv_hist_simple` (sku, cost, price, QtyInStock, change_date) 
          VALUES(OLD.sku_m, NEW.cost, NEW.price, NEW.QtyInStock, NOW());
    END IF;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: That absolutely did it. Thanks! ****happy dance****